# how to called a class on a echo php

Tags: php

I got the following line:

```
$anuncios3 = "<a class=resize2 target=_blank href=../anuncios/conteo.php?thumbnail=$anuncios_general[2]>".$anuncios_general[3]."</a>"; //publicacion anuncio
```

I need to include the resize2 class because it will help me to fit a text inside a table, but it seems it's not being taking in account by php as if it was not there.

```
<style type="text/css" >

.resize2{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't care or affect CSS. It's just regular text. Also, use quotes around your attribute values. Not doing so is sloppy. Also, your CSS class would only work on block level elements. Anchor tags are inline elemtents.

Comment: i have realize that my dear friend. Is there any suggestion to what i need or you just down vote dump questions just because you want?. I'd be more than glad to read your solution

Comment: @Alejo_Blue can you verify that the class is being applied (use web inspector / firebug). You might not see the desired effect because your css definition is incomplete. `overflow` wont work without specifying a `width`, you might also need to up the element to a `block` level element (or `inline-block`). Also, keep in mind that anyone can downvote, no need to give John a hard time for it.

Comment: thanks, but in fact this class is working fine on another table but not in this one :(. I don't think the problem is the css class but when i called from php.

Comment: You can try to apply that class to a span or a div, in which you'll write the "a" tag. Something like <div class="resize2"><a href="#"></a></div>

Comment: @Jackerbil thank you so much! indeed this worked for me!!! thank to al who provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for echo and double quotes for html attributes.

```
$anuncios3 = '<a class="resize2" target="_blank" href="../anuncios/conteo.php?thumbnail='.$anuncios_general[2].'">'.$anuncios_general[3].'</a>';
```